# How to formulate this biased coin toss problem?

Tags: probability

I have a biased coin where $\alpha = 0.2$ is the probability of heads, and $1-\alpha = 0.8$ is the probability of tails.

I have numbers 1 to 64, and if I land on heads I will remove the first half of the numbers in the set. If I land on tails, I remove the upper half of the set.

If I wanted to calculate the probability of obtaining a number $n$ within the interval [1,64], I'm not sure how to formalise this problem?

For a much simpler problem for numbers 1 to 4, I can see that the probability of obtaining n:

1: (1-$\alpha$)(1-$\alpha$)

2: (1-$\alpha$)$\alpha$

3: $\alpha$(1-$\alpha$)

4: $\alpha$$\alpha$

However, I'm not sure how to write out the formula for arbitrary n on the range 1 to 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sequence $a_n$ given by the [number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$](http://oeis.org/A000120). There is no nice formula for this sequence.

Once you have that sequence, we get that the probability that the final result is the number $k$ is given by
$$
(1-\alpha)^{a_{k+1}}\alpha^{6-a_{k+1}}
$$
(The reason for $k+1$ is that this is more naturally done with the integers from $0$ to $63$. In that case, the coin tosses are actually the binary expansion of the number $k$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider your numbers written in binary and rather than working with the range $1$-$64$ work instead with the numbers in the range $0$-$63$.  You can adjust after the fact later.  Now... compare what sequence of tosses are required to arrive at a particular number and how it relates to the number as it were written in binary.